# Laravel realtionship sometimes not functional

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, laravel-5.3

I have Laravel 5. framework for bacis e-shop, i try use relationship I have Order, Order_item, Product, Customer model

Order model has realationship with

```
class Order extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'status'];

    protected $dates = ['created_at'];

    /**
     * Get the items for the order.
     */
    public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Order_item');
    }

    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Customer','id');
    }
}
```

Order item

```
class Order_item extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['order_id', 'product_id', 'quantity', 'price'];

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Product','id');
    }
}
```

in controller

```
public function detail($id)
    {
        $order = Order::with('customer','items')->findOrFail($id);

        return view('admin.detail', ['order' => $order]);

    }
```

and in view I have

```
<h2>Objednávka č. {{ $order->id }}</h2>
    <h3>Zákazník:</h3>
        {{ $order->customer->firstname }} {{ $order->customer->lastname }}
        <p>{{ $order->customer->email }}</p>
        {{ $order->customer->phone }}
    <h3>Adresa:</h3>
        <p>{{ $order->customer->street }}</p>
        <p>{{ $order->customer->city }}</p>
        <p>{{ $order->customer->psc }}</p>
    <h3>Položky:</h3>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <th>Název</th>
            <th>Počet</th>
            <th>Cena</th>
        </thead>
            <tbody>
            @foreach($order->items  as $item)
                <tr>
                    <th>{{ $item->product->name }}</th>
                    <th>{{ $item->quantity }}</th>
                    <th>{{ $item->price }}</th>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

and now when i test the code for someone order is function but for someone no, the problem is on {{ $item->product->name }}

is my realationship ok? Its a better solution for my e-shop relationship

i post my complete code to github https://github.com/mardon/MaMushashop

Comment: Let's [take this to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124553/laravel-site-wide-var). It's easier that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your order item table is a [pivot table](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many). There for the relationships to order and product should be declared as belongsToMany.

- **belongsToMany** is used in Many To Many.
- **hasMany** is used in a One To Many
- **hasOne** is used in One To One

The naming of your table Order_item should be order_product to better reflect what it actually contains.

```html
class order_product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['order_id', 'product_id', 'quantity', 'price'];

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'order_product', 'order_id', 'product_id);
    }

    public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order', 'order_product', 'product_id', 'order_id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
$order = DB::table('order')
->join('customer', 'order.customer_id', '=', 'customer.id')
->select('order.*', 'customer.*')
->where('order.id', '=', $id)
->first();
$order_items = Order_item::where('order_id', $id)->get();

return view('admin.detail', ['order' => $order, 'order_items' => $order_items]);
```

And generate item like this

```
@foreach($order_items as $item)
    <tr>
        <th>{{ $item->product->name }}</th>
        <th>{{ $item->quantity }}</th>
        <th>{{ $item->price }}</th>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: this code produce same problem two order delais are alrightin view and two no with error Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: $order = Order::where('id', $id)->first();

Comment: still same problem

Comment: Sorry query is wrong.. use this $order = DB::table('order')
->join('customer', 'order.customer_id', '=', 'customer.id')
->select('order.*', 'customer.*')
->where('order.id', '=', $id)
->first();